backdrop-blur not working in modal using tailwindcss
I want to blur the background when the modal pops up and currently it does not work
HTML:
<!-- modal -->
    <div id="modal" class="w-4/5 sm:3/4 md:w-2/3 lg:w-1/2 bg-gray-300 shadow-xl rounded-xl flex flex-col gap-4 absolute -top-75 left-1/2 transform -translate-x-1/2 -translate-y-1/2 z-40 transition-all duration-700 p-5">
        <div class="flex items-center justify-between px-4">
            <h5 class="font-lg mt-2 mb-1">مرتب سازی بر اساس</h5>
            <span class="material-symbols-outlined cursor-pointer" id="close-modal">close</span>
        </div>
        <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
            <div class="modal-item cursor-pointer bg-#3C6E71 rounded-lg shadow-lg m-1 p-4 text-white">جدیدترین</div>
            <div class="modal-item cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg m-1 p-4 text-#353535">قدیمی ترین</div>
            <div class="modal-item cursor-pointer bg-white rounded-lg shadow-lg m-1 p-4 text-#353535">محبوب ترین</div>
        </div>
    </div>

javascript:
const btnOpenModal = document.querySelector('#change-sort-type')
const modal = document.querySelector('#modal')
const btnCloseModal = document.querySelector('#close-modal')
const modalBoxItems = document.querySelectorAll('.modal-item')

window.onload = function () {
    function setSearchType (event) {
        modalBoxItems.forEach(function (item) {
            item.classList.remove('text-white')
            item.classList.remove('bg-#3C6E71')
            item.classList.add('text-#353535')
            item.classList.add('bg-white')
        })
        event.target.classList.remove('bg-white')
        event.target.classList.remove('text-#353535')
        event.target.classList.add('bg-#3C6E71')
        event.target.classList.add('text-white')
        btnOpenModal.children[1].innerHTML = event.target.innerHTML
        closeModal()
    }
    
    function openModal () {
        modal.classList.remove('-top-75')
        modal.classList.add('top-1/2')
        document.body.classList.add('modal-active')
        modal.classList.add('backdrop-blur-lg')
    }
    function closeModal () {
        modal.classList.remove('top-1/2')
        modal.classList.add('-top-75')
        document.body.classList.remove('modal-active')
        modal.classList.remove('backdrop-blur-lg')
    }
    
    btnOpenModal.addEventListener('click', openModal)
    btnCloseModal.addEventListener('click', closeModal)
    
    modalBoxItems.forEach(function (item) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            setSearchType(event)
        })
    })
}

So I tried using backdrop-blur on both the modal and the body element and set an click event for opening the modal to blur the background in js, when blurring the modal, the modal itself blurs but when blurring the body, nothing happens, both situation not giving me the wanted result.
